# How to change the height of the view based on width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have ConstraintLayout with 4 ImageViews inside, and I need to put for any ImageView weight like LinearLayout and change the height of the view based on width.

**This is what I need:**

[image]

So as you can see here I have 4 views with the same width and the height change like the width.

After I show you what I trying to do, this is my status right now:

[image]

**This is the layout:**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/label_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

NOTE:
my asset @drawable/a is 40X40

How can I get the same result as in the example I attached?

Comment: There is an error with the `constraintEnd` in the 3rd ImageView causing the chain to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think that placing the four image views in a chain anchored to the start and end of the `ConstraintLayout` parent with a height of `wrap_content` as you have defined would give the desired result. Unfortunately, in my best estimation, the chain is not sufficient to force the layout to "open up" and assume the correct height. The only thing in your layout that gives the layout height is your drawables; the chain does not cause the layout to open up enough to assume the specified ratios.

It is unclear to me whether this behavior is just how `ConstraintLayout` works or if it is a defect. Regardless, the work-around for this is to force the layout to open up to let the chain size itself and its member views appropriately. To force the layout to open up, we will define a `Space` view as follows:

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The vertical guideline is set at 25% of the width of the layout because each `ImageView` will take up 25% of the layout's width. `0dp` is `match_constraints`. The ratio forces the correct height of the `Space` and, therefore, the height of the layout. This `Space` is not visible in the layout, but is enough to give the layout vertical dimension.

The entire XML file is below. There was an error in the chain at `label_3` which has been corrected. I also changed the height of all `ImageViews` to `0dp` so the `ImageViews` could assume the desired ratios. I did remove the drawables, so they will need to be reintroduced with the appropriate `scaleType` defined. What you see in the screen shot is the extents of the `ImageViews`.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/label_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffea00"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/label_1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1.15"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```